# How do I show or hide a <td> on select menu?

Tags: javascript, select

I have two `<td>`'s next to each other.  They are both `<select>` dropdown menus.  I would like to show one if, and only if, the first one has an option value or id of `scantron`.

My function is as follows:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function EnableDisableTD() {
              if ($("#scantron").attr("selected")) {
                  $("#version").show();
              } else {
              $("#version").hide();
              }};
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<td><select>
  <option selected="selected">Computer Based Format</option>
  <option id="scantron">Scantron Format</option>
</select></td>
<td id="version"><select name="version">
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select></td>
```

Why is this not working for me?

Comment: Where do you call `EnableDisableTD()`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. You may have not been using a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.

```
function EnableDisableTD() {
  $('#version')[$('#scantron').attr('selected')) ? 'show' : 'hide']();
}

// Document ready
$(EnableDisableTD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the `td`, not the `select`.

Comment: you mean `<td id="scantron">...</td>`  I tried that, but it still shows up... Do I have to display:none;?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the "version" id in the td instead of the select:

```
...   
<td id="version"><select name="version">
      <option selected="selected">1</option>
...
```